# How to display the number of days elapsed between two dates denoted in columns-specifically those exceeding 30 days?

Tags: oracle, datetime

Perhaps I'm overthinking this Oracle SQL query, but I'm attempting to display the number of days elapsed between two column data-sets attributed as "order-date" and "ship-date", which will be displayed within a new alias column, "Number of Days elapsed"- so far, I've constructed the following query:

```
SELECT order_id,
       (shipped_date - order_date) AS "Number of Days elapsed"
FROM orders;
```

Evidently, an alias column can't be sorted or filtered- so what options are available to filter the resulting output for the number of orders exceeding 30 days to ship?

Comment: I don't have oracle available to tinker on, but have you tried something along the lines of `WHERE (shipped_date - order_date) > 30 ORDER BY (shipped_date - order_date)` ?

Comment: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either restate the calculation in the predicate

```
SELECT order_id,
       (shipped_date - order_date) AS "Number of Days elapsed"
FROM orders
WHERE shipped_date - order_date > 30
ORDER BY (shipped_date - order_date) desc;
```

or nest the query

```
SELECT order_id, "Number of Days elapsed"
  FROM (SELECT order_id,
               (shipped_date - order_date) AS "Number of Days elapsed"
          FROM orders)
 WHERE "Number of Days elapsed" > 30
 ORDER BY "Number of Days elapsed" desc
```

If you are going to nest the query, though, it probably makes sense to pick a case-insensitive alias in the inner query and to do the case-sensitive aliasing later on

```
SELECT order_id, days_elapsed "Number of Days elapsed"
  FROM (SELECT order_id,
               (shipped_date - order_date) days_elapsed
          FROM orders)
 WHERE days_elapsed > 30
 ORDER BY days_elapsed  desc
```

Comment: thank you- your first submission is the most elegant but I also appreciate the nested approaches-well done, sir!  Thanks again.

Comment: @alexanderjsingleton - It depends.  For simple calculations like this, I find repeating them in the `where` clause easiest.  But as you get more and more complicated calculations, it makes more sense to use a nesting approach.

Comment: @alexanderjsingleton - updated.

Comment: LOL-just deleted my comment; I resolved via your last nested-query solution-thanks again!